# Is being 'Sect-less' frowned upon?

Tags: worship, sects

There are umpteen sects (Sampradāyas) in Hinduism.

Does any text enjoin to have a sectarian identity in all the believers of Hinduism?

Is it frowned upon if the person doesn’t identify with any traditional sect?

Is it okay to not subscribe to any traditional sect, and just worship a chosen Vedic-deity, with no sectarian philosophy?

<sup>Scriptural sources are preferred but views of acharyas are also welcome.</sup>

Comment: You have multiple questions in this question. See the forum rules. One of your questions is asking for opinions. See forum rules.

Comment: It's the same question with elucidation in various statements @Vishwananda. Please Re-visit - [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for an update on how this community works. Thanks!

Comment: general opinion is - you don't get to meet the PM directly without an introduction/reference. Similarly, you don't get to meet Bhagavan without an acharya (who in turn, has an acharya, who in turn.. all the way to Bhagavan himself the first acharya). Of course there can be exceptional circumstances, but even those are apparent, because at some point in the past, they would have had the kataksham of a saint.